# Unit testing, how to make spring management services do not pollute the database

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-transactions

I'm trying to use the **spring and junit** test DAO method, I see some of the practice on the Internet is the use of spring statement-style transaction management (@Transactional) for business operations, said that after the test is completed, the spring will let the test method back Roll, so as to achieve the purpose of testing.

Then I follow this approach to add the operation of the method of dao tested and found that the transaction submitted, **the rollback is not successful**, the database I came out of the test data. At first I thought it was spring did not roll back, but behind the observation console print information found to have rollback information, but why would fail, do not know. I found some related programs, but I found that did not solve my problem. Very troubled, hope to get your help!

*The following is my code and file configuration*

- DAOImpl's addUser () method

  ```
  @Override
  public void addUser(User u) {
      Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
      Transaction tc = session.getTransaction();
      try {
          tc.begin();
          session.save(u);
          tc.commit();
      }catch(Exception e){
          tc.rollback();
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return ;
  }
  ```
- Daos.xml file configuration

  ```
  <bean id="txManager"

      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
      <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory" />
  </bean>
  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
  ```

Test class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"/services.xml"})
@Transactional(transactionManager = "txManager")
@Rollback(true)
 public class UserServiceImplTest {
    @Autowired
    UserDAO userDAO; 

    @Test
    public void testAddUse(){
        User u = new User();
        u.setLevel(3);
        u.setName("ab11");
        u.setPassword("hh");
        userDAO.addUser(u);
        Assert.assertEquals(u.getName(), userDAO.getUserList().get(userDAO.getUserList().size()-1).getName());
    }
```

Some of the console prints information

```
INFO: Using DataSource [org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource@498d318c] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
    JUNE 02, 2017 4:46:19 afternoon org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionContext startTransaction
INFO: Began transaction (1) for test context [DefaultTestContext@52d6cd34 testClass = UserServiceImplTest, testInstance = com.dxzh.mall.serviceImpl.test.UserServiceImplTest@715d6168, testMethod = testAddUse@UserServiceImplTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@75798d03 testClass = UserServiceImplTest, locations = '{classpath:/services.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextCustomizers = set[[empty]], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]]; transaction manager [org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager@c6634d]; rollback [true]
    Fri Jun 02 16:46:19 CST 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
    Hibernate: insert into user (name, password, level) values (?, ?, ?)
    JUNE 02, 2017 4:46:19 afternoon org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionContext endTransaction
INFO: Rolled back transaction for test context [DefaultTestContext@52d6cd34 testClass = UserServiceImplTest, testInstance = com.dxzh.mall.serviceImpl.test.UserServiceImplTest@715d6168, testMethod = testAddUse@UserServiceImplTest, testException = java.lang.RuntimeException, mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@75798d03 testClass = UserServiceImplTest, locations = '{classpath:/services.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextCustomizers = set[[empty]], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]].
    JUNE 02, 2017 4:46:19 afternoon org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext doClose
INFO: Closing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@3ffc5af1: startup date [Fri Jun 02 16:46:13 CST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
```

Comment: For the record: when a test touches a **database** then don't call it a *unit* test.

Comment: @GhostCat  Thanks for your advice.But I still do not know how to make spring rollback.

Comment: Rest assured :if I had had an answer, I would have given it. That's why I am here. Most of the time.:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, you are mixing a pair of concepts here.

Your production code manages the transaction DIRECTLY, while your test code uses AOP (aspect oriented programming) spring annotations.

Since your production code manages the transaction, the AOP annotations in your test code are totally useless: the transaction witch rules is the one inside your production code.

The solution: use AOP in your production code also. Let the robust and well tested Spring transaction mechanism to manage the transaction and forget about managing it yourself. Something like this:

```
@Override
@Transactional(transactionManager = "txManager")
public void addUser(User u) {
    // only your bussiness logic here
}
```

More info: [here (example)](http://www.journaldev.com/2603/spring-transaction-management-jdbc-example) and [here(Spring manal)](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html)

---

[This wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_testing) explains quite well different software testing approaches. Yours falls under the category *integration test*

Comment: Thank you very much, your question is helpful to me. I found the solution. Because I did not use the transaction correctly, so the rollback failed!
I began to realize that:
1. production code should not be the management of the transaction;
2. should use getCurrentSession () and should not use openSession ().

Comment: You are welcome. Happy you learned that. I learned it the hard way ;)